# I have a json without any keys and I would like to get the values into a class object in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

This is the sample JSON I would like to parse :

```json
[
  [
    1617235200000,
    "58739.46000000",
    "59490.00000000",
    "57935.45000000",
    "58720.44000000",
    "47415.61722000",
    1617321599999,
    "2789238879.94337348",
    1594431,
    "22966.25673600",
    "1351151697.89222195",
    "0"
  ]
]
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: seems like a `List` night be in order.

Comment: I tried List<object> but then what. How do i get the  values out of it

Comment: [C# List Tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/c-sharp-list/). You should probably be using a `List<double>` or `List<decimal>` or `List<List<double>>` or `List<List<decimal>>`.

Comment: You cant index an object. This cannot be solved with just just a list. There's something more to it. Some of the values are strings

Comment: `List<List<object>>` should be fine - that should be able to handle both numbers and strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind treating all values in the inner List as string using a `List<List<string>>` will work. Notice that your Json is basically an array of arrays.

```
var json = @"[ [ 1617235200000, ""58739.46000000"", ""59490.00000000"", ""57935.45000000"", ""58720.44000000"", ""47415.61722000"", 1617321599999, ""2789238879.94337348"", 1594431, ""22966.25673600"", ""1351151697.89222195"", ""0"" ] ]";

var ser = new JsonSerializer();
var lists = ser.Deserialize<List<List<string>>>(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json))); 

var innerList = lists[0];
var secondItem = innerList[1].Dump("second item");
var lastItem = innerList.Last().Dump("last item");
```

This will output (when using LinqPad, that is where the Dump helper extension comes from):

**second item**
58739.46000000

**last item**
0

Alternatively you could use `List<List<object>>` but then you have figure out later what type you're dealing with.